# facing OpenIdConnectProtocolException : Invalid_Token error

Tags: identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

I have one Master application(MainApp) and one Client Application(clientApp). I am trying to login ClientApp through MainApp.(Having a Login button in ClientApp and it will go to MainApp for login). I did setup in Startup.cs file as below in ClientApp:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OneIAM", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
            options.ClientId = "XXXXXX858";
            options.ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHDDH6os6/xJr7qGmmSJQxViHiq585KdghDaLnQ1Rb03J==";

            options.CallbackPath = "/Index";
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc";

            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");

            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        });
```

In above code, "*https://localhost:5001*" is the URL for MainApp.

I have register ClientId and ClientSecret in MainApp using below code :

```
dotnet user-secrets set 'HttpClient:CbApi:ClientId' 'XXXX858'
dotnet user-secrets set 'HttpClient:CbApi:ClientSecret' 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHDDH6os6/xJr7qGmmSJQxViHiq585KdghDaLnQ1Rb03J=='
```

Now, after running both(MainApp and ClientApp), I have Login button on ClientApp and after clicking on Login button it's redirecting to MainApp login page. But, after providing credential and hitting login button, it's showing error as below

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

**FYI : i have maintained all the client info in database table as well**

Please help me in this and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: What does the entry in the client database look like for that client ID?

Comment: actually actual client id is bit different in real and both side(Startup.cs and Database) has same clientid. I am trying to redirect my Index page in ClientApp after successful login in MainApp.

Comment: if you get invalid_client, then the clientid in the client and what IdentityServer thinks is the clientId is different.... I would add some more logging or single step through the database layer.

Comment: Could you please share some code which could help me in this scenario.

Comment: A starting point can be to use the InMemory Client/resource store and when that works, move to use a database.  Otherwise there's to many source of errors here.